Why is the UI not updating immediately after a follow/unfollow mutation?
I am working on a recipe-sharing application using Next.js, and I'm trying to implement a follow/unfollow feature. The feature uses React Query (TanStack Query) for state management, and while the follow/unfollow functionality works correctly (data updates in the backend), the UI only reflects the changes after a page reload instead of updating immediately.
Here's the relevant code for my Tanstack Query setup:
Services for Follow/Unfollow:
export const followUser = async (followeeId: string) => {
    const accessToken = cookies().get('accessToken')?.value;
    if (!accessToken) console.error("Access token missing");
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.post(`/follow/${followeeId}`, {}, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    });
    return data;
};

export const unfollowUser = async (followeeId: string) => {
    const accessToken = cookies().get('accessToken')?.value;
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.delete(`/follow/unFollow/${followeeId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    });
    return data;
};


React Query Mutations:
export const useFollow = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    return useMutation<void, Error, { followeeId: string }>({
        mutationKey: ["FOLLOW"],
        mutationFn: async ({ followeeId }) => await followUser(followeeId),
        onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success("Followed successfully.");
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["FOLLOWEES"] });
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            const errorMessage = error.message || "An error occurred.";
            toast.error(errorMessage);
        },
    });
};

export const useUnfollow = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    return useMutation<void, Error, { followeeId: string }>({
        mutationKey: ["UNFOLLOW"],
        mutationFn: async ({ followeeId }) => await unfollowUser(followeeId),
        onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success("Unfollowed successfully.");
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["FOLLOWEES"] });
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            const errorMessage = error.message || "An error occurred.";
            toast.error(errorMessage);
        },
    });
};


Query for Fetching Followees:
export const useGetFollowees = (id: string) => {
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["FOLLOWEES", id],
        queryFn: () => getFollowees(id),
        staleTime: 1000, // Keep data fresh for 1 second
        enabled: !!id, // Only run the query if `id` is defined
    });
};


How I Handle Follow/Unfollow in the Component:
const followees = useGetFollowees(currentUserId);
const followeesId = followees?.data?.map((f) => f?._id);
const isFollowing = followeesId?.includes(userId);

const { mutate: handleFollow } = useFollow();
const { mutate: handleUnFollow } = useUnfollow();

const handleFollowUser = () => {
    handleFollow({ followeeId: userId });
};

const handleUnFollowUser = () => {
    handleUnFollow({ followeeId: userId });
};


Problem:
Even though the onSuccess callback for useFollow and useUnfollow calls queryClient.invalidateQueries to refetch the followees list, the UI does not reflect the updated state immediately. Instead, I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated list of followees.
I suspect this issue might be related to:

React Query's cache behavior not triggering an immediate re-render.
Some aspect of Next.js causing the delay in UI updates.
My query or mutation setup missing something.

What I've Tried:

Verified that the followUser and unfollowUser functions are working and returning the correct data from the backend.

Tried reducing the staleTime in useGetFollowees to 0 to force React Query to refetch immediately.


Questions:

Is there an issue with how I'm using invalidateQueries?
Is there something specific to Next.js that might be interfering with React Query's behavior?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
